paho.mqtt.c build and run the included tests
The question is how to benefit from the included to the paho.mqtt.c repository paho.c tests. After compiling all with:
    mkdir buil && cd build
    cmake -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=TRUE -DPAHO_BUILD_SAMPLES=TRUE -DPAHO_ENABLE_TESTING=TRUE ..
    make

The folder test is in the build folder and the tests are inside.
I would like to perform the provided tests. The instructions in the readme are:
    python ../test/mqttsas.py &
    ctest -VV

This part is not clear how to perform. Any idea on how to launch the provided tests?

What is not clear? the paragraph above those instructions says you need a broker running on localhost on the test machine, then run those commands.
